# My cat has a sort of.. pattern by her tail

Tags: cats, health

I have a cat called Tink. She is 6 years old, and she has a sort of.. pattern, if you'd like to call it by that, on her part by her tail. I thought it was a bald patch at first, but I looked up images of the bald patches and it doesn't look like one.

I have a picture, sorry for the bad quality.

[image: A picture of the peculiar thing.]

Does ANYBODY know what it is? How did it come up?

Answer (score 2):

Based on what I can see from this picture, it looks a bit like what one of my cats has.

My ~26 pound cat can't bathe himself completely, so he gets filthy near his back end, right where your cat has the issue. Therefore there's constantly dirt and other things clumped up there which causes irritability for him. We bathe him ourselves regularly, but the area stays fairly sensitive.

Whenever there is a flea or tick outbreak we go to this shampoo which eases his irritability for a while [Adams Plus Flea & Tick Shampoo with Precor](https://www.chewy.com/adams-plus-flea-tick-shampoo-precor/dp/102579?utm_source=google-product&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=hg&utm_content=Adams&utm_term=&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI-_mTsOOf1AIVibbACh10BQ4kEAQYAyABEgLdPfD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)

Hope this helps.